# Sign-in with Google not working on some Android Devices

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I want my users to have two types of sign-in options - "Sign in with email" and "Sign in with Google". I my application I am using `firebase-core:11.8.0`, `firebase-auth:11.8.0'` and `firebase-ui-auth:3.2.1'`.

When I run it on most physical and emulator devices, it works perfectly fine. However, on some devices (mainly with API 27), `"Sign in with Google"` fails. The log says -

```
E/CredentialSignInHandler: Unexpected exception when signing in with credential google.com unsuccessful. Visit https://console.firebase.google.com to enable it.
                       com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Invalid id_token in IdP response:eyJhbG....., error: Id_token failed validation. ]
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxm.zzao(Unknown Source:133)
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwn.zza(Unknown Source:43)
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxx.zzap(Unknown Source:11)
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdya.onFailure(Unknown Source:35)
                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxo.onTransact(Unknown Source:79)
                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

I can confirm both sign in methods are enabled in the console and the updated `google-services.json` is in the `app` directory.

I am pasting my code here, in case that helps.

```
package com.pustack.android.pustack;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Authentication
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize Firebase Authentication
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser currentUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                updateUI(currentUser);

            }
        };
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
            finish();
        }
    }
}

private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        new CountDownTimer(1000,1000){
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){}

            @Override
            public void onFinish(){
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        }.start();
    } else {
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
                        .setLogo(R.mipmap.pustack_full_logo_vertical_white)
                        .setTheme(R.style.LoginTheme)
                        .setAvailableProviders(Arrays.asList(
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build(),
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build()))
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mAuthStateListener != null)
        mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
}
```

I am struggling with this bug for a while now, contacted firebase support and they confirmed that everything is good on their side.

Comment: So you filed a bug report, and they said they ran your code and it worked?

Comment: They did not run my code, my question to them was more on the lines of if "Sign in with Google" is working fine with API 27. Firebase support does not entertain requests asking them to run a specific code or debugging help.

Comment: If it says you haven't enabled the auth provider, 99% likely that's the cause. If you're certain it's enabled, those devices may have an outdated version of your API keys or be pointed to the wrong project. Support will help if you provide a simple repro that demonstrates a behavior which contradicts our docs. They will not help you debug your code. If you think you've provided that and they haven't helped, email me and I'll investigate: katowulf@google.com